Vulnerabilities of a word-level substitution cipher
What kind of attacks would be possible against this kind of substitution cipher?

Every word in the plaintext is to be replaced with a random string of the same length
The encryption of any given word will remain consistent (a dictionary [plaintext word -> ciphertext word] is to be maintained)


In case you're interested in our reading list.

TL;DR: Word based substitution is not strong, given modern computational capabilities.
If you have a dictionary of common words, you can to do frequency analysis either on a word basis or on a global character basis.
The word basis analysis would be a little trickier if you have no "space" symbol so you cannot see word boundaries at the ciphertext. Still, by standard methods such as looking for the most common english words' encipherment this can be broken given enough ciphertext.
For example English word frequencies are given below:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rtatman/english-word-frequency
not surprisingly the most common words are

the, of, and, to, a, in, for, is, on, that, by, this, with ...

If you have a word with relative frequency $p$ (divide by the total number of words in the corpus) on average it will appear after $1/p$ samples or so.
